# What languages besides Objective-C will generate application code that works on an iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, code-generation, macruby

I would like to write an app for the iPad but I can't stand Objective-C.

Is there a language generator that would spit out Objective-C but let me write my iPad application in another language?

I've heard a little about MacRuby and am curious whether it could be used this way. Any other similar projects in other languages?

Comment: This type of question has been asked before. There are language generators that can generate the code you want (I can't recall the name of one atm) but the bigger obstacle you will find is not the language/syntax but the APIs you'll have to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# with [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/).
JavaScript with [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/).
Flex with [ELIPS Studio 3](http://www.flex888.com/1466/flex-on-iphone.html).
Python with [PyObjC](http://www.saurik.com/id/5) (for jailbroken iPhones though).

Comment: And apple has banned them all! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently [Lua](http://github.com/probablycorey/wax) is an option.

Answer (score 1):

[John McIntosh](http://www.smalltalkconsulting.com/) uses Smalltalk on the iPhone. For instance, his [Mobile Wiki Server](http://www.mobilewikiserver.com/) app.

Answer (score 0):

No computer anywhere (well maybe some) cares what language you write your programs in.  Heck, you could hand-write machine instructions if you were patient (and crazy) enough.  As long as you can figure out how to interact properly with the system call interface and the ABI, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: However, steve jobs cares, a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Corona](http://anscamobile.com/corona/), [Torque](http://www.torquepowered.com/products/torque-2d/iphone), or [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). These all have advantages and disadvantages compared to using the standard Objective-C SDK, but really, if it's about the *language* itself, it's hard to see how you would be better able to "stand" the languages supported by these three than Objective-C.